# Passing props to custom header in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to pass function as a prop to custom header in react native navigation 6.0. I need to update state in my parent screen from header component when a button on header clicked. Any code pointers or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set headerLeft with navigation.setOption

```
const navigation = useNavigation()

useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerLeft: () => <Button onPress={onPress}>Your button</Button>,
  })
}, [navigation])
```